# How to configure a service auto-restart after failure with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, service

On a Windows system, in the Service console, there is a recovery tab to configure actions for a service in case of failure.

[image: Recovery Options when managing a Windows Service]

How can I configure this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is currently no native PowerShell cmdlet to manage the service recovery.
However, to auto-restart a service when it fails you can use `SC`.
(In a PowerShell prompt you must precede it with & and use the full name `sc.exe`)

```bash
& sc.exe failure msftpsvc reset= 30 actions= restart/5000

##reset in sec, rest in ms
## example for 1 day reset and 2min restart, twice before take no action
& sc.exe failure myService reset= 86400 actions= restart/120000/restart/240000/""/240000
```

The official documentation is on **Microsoft Docs** under [Sc Failure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc742019(v%3Dws.11))

Answer (score 3):

Abstract from https://evotec.xyz/set-service-recovery-options-powershell/

```
 function Set-ServiceRecovery{
    [alias('Set-Recovery')]
    param
    (
        [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $ServiceDisplayName,
        [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Server,
        [string] $action1 = "restart",
        [int] $time1 =  30000, # in miliseconds
        [string] $action2 = "restart",
        [int] $time2 =  30000, # in miliseconds
        [string] $actionLast = "restart",
        [int] $timeLast = 30000, # in miliseconds
        [int] $resetCounter = 4000 # in seconds
    )
    $serverPath = "\\" + $server
    $services = Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Service' -ComputerName $Server| Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -imatch $ServiceDisplayName}
    $action = $action1+"/"+$time1+"/"+$action2+"/"+$time2+"/"+$actionLast+"/"+$timeLast
    foreach ($service in $services){
        # https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019.aspx
        $output = sc.exe $serverPath failure $($service.Name) actions= $action reset= $resetCounter
    }
}
Set-ServiceRecovery -ServiceDisplayName "Pulseway" -Server "MAIL1"
```